# How to use androidx.recyclerview with Facebook Audience Network SDK?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, facebook-ads-api

I have a list of elements in a RecyclerView, to make life easier I am using `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0`.

I am trying to load Ads from Facebook as described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android (they are using `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1`).

I have already added the support library `recyclerview-v7` and `support-v4`. But the FBAudienceNetwork still gives me this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"

...

Dependency not found: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
Dependency not found: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

...

 java.lang.RuntimeException: Facebook Audience Network SDK doesn't have all required classes. Please, check LogCat output for tag FBAudienceNetwork. See more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/ . You can change Integration Error mode by setting AdSettings.setIntegrationErrorMode()
```

Is there a way to "force" FBAudienceNetwork to use my `androidx.recyclerview` instead of the `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7` or is there a way these two can work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are already aware, but just in case... This is happening because the Facebook SDK is dependent on the pre-`androidx` version of `RecyclerView`, and you are using the `androidx` version in your app.

You could downgrade your own dependency, so that both your app and the Facebook SDK are using the version of `RecyclerView` that lives in the `android.support.v7.widget` package.

Or, you could use [the Jetifier tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier) to dynamically re-write the Facebook SDK's dependency so that it uses the version of `RecyclerView` that lives in the `androidx.recyclerview.widget` package.

The easiest way to do the second option is to follow the steps listed on the [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) document:

> [...] set the following two flags to `true` in your `gradle.properties` file:
>
> ```
> android.useAndroidX=true
> android.enableJetifier=true
> ```

Comment: Downgrade my dependency is what I am trying to avoid. I am not sure if “dynamically re-writing the Facebook SDK's dependency” is a real option as I am scared  Facebook will kick me out of their add problem once I temper with their SDK. I thought I was just missing something :(

Comment: The use of jetifier is pretty standard; I'd be surprised if Facebook did that. The other option is to wait for Facebook to release a new version of their SDK that depends on AndroidX.

Comment: I asked facebook support about using jetifier and will write back once I get an answer.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2492140071006423/?disable_redirect=0 looks like jetifier is the only option when using AndroidX.

Comment: I think it's really cool that you put in the effort to contact Facebook and get an official response on this